# How to get timezone hour offset and account for DST with PEAR::Date?

Tags: php, timezone, pear, dst

I am trying to get the offset hours from UTC, given a summer date. My system time is set to America/Los_Angeles.

I have the following:

```
require_once("Date.php");

$dateTZ = new Date_TimeZone('America/Los_Angeles');

echo $dateTZ->getOffset(new Date('2009-07-01 12:00:00'))/1000/60/60;
```

This prints '-8'; shouldn't it show '-7'?

```
echo $dateTZ->getOffset(new Date())/1000/60/60;
```

also prints '-8'.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does [Date::inDaylightTime()](http://pear.php.net/package/Date/docs/latest/Date/Date.html#methodinDaylightTime) help you? [Date::getTZOffset](http://pear.php.net/package/Date/docs/latest/Date/Date.html#methodgetTZOffset) claims to include daylight savings offset.

Comment: Date_TimeZone->inDaylightTime(Date) works. I had tried that before, but I had been using it incorrectly. Thanks.